# Spacing bar between bars is too high in a bar plot with error bars

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

```
   \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = {ring enrich.},
ybar,
width=10cm,
xtick={1,2},
xticklabels={%
    before,
    after,
}]
\addplot[
   fill=blue!25,
   draw=black,
   error bars/.cd,
   y dir=both,
   y explicit
] 
table [y error=error] {
x   y       error
1   6.63    3.95
};

\addplot[
   fill=red!25,
   draw=black,
   error bars/.cd,
   y dir=both,
   y explicit
] 
table [y error=c] {
x   y       c
2   41.58   8.48
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thanks, the comma thing was my oversight. Even though I haven't understood why changing xbar to ybar solves the problem.

Comment: Also may I ask for another problem? I've got another simpler bar plot. the problem is bars are too far from each other, what can I do?

Comment: '\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = {ring enrich.},
ybar,
width=10cm,
barwidth=5pt,
xtick={1,2},
xticklabels={%
    before,
    after,
}]
\addplot[
   fill=blue!25,
   draw=black,
   ybar,
   error bars/.cd,
   y dir=both,
   y explicit
] 
table [y error=error] {
x   y       error
1 6.63 3.95
};

\addplot[
   fill=red!25,
   draw=black,
   ybar,
   error bars/.cd,
   y dir=both,
   y explicit
] 
table [y error=c] {
x   y       c
2 41.58 8.48
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}'

Comment: sorry don't know how to insert a code in the comment!

Comment: @Jake thanks for helping, I moved ybar to the axis option but it didn't work, anyway I'll work it out, have a nice day

Comment: @jake sorry for the late replay, I posted the new bar plot in place of the old one, the problem is the distance between the bars, thank you

Comment: There are three ways to reduce the space between the bars: Move the bars closer together while keeping the width of the plot, reducing the width of the plot (and thereby moving the bars closer together), or increasing the width of the bars. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Probably a combination of the first and the third option would be great, if not possible I think the first one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can move the bars closer while keeping the overall plot width constant by setting `enlarge x limits=<value>`, where `<value>` specifies by what fraction you want to increase the axis range. To make the bars wider, you can set `bar width=<width>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, bar shift=0pt,
bar width=1cm,
enlarge x limits=0.5,
width=10cm,
xtick={1,2},
]
\addplot[
   fill=blue!25,
   draw=black
] 
table{
x   y       error
1   6.63    3.95
};

\addplot[
   fill=red!25,
   draw=black
] 
table {
x   y       c
2   41.58   8.48
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```